# NetworkManager does not start unless a users logs in first

Tags: networking, network-manager, gui

I installed Ubuntu 20.10 in a VM, with GNOME and have been using it with NetworkManager for a while now.

```
juan@box:~$ uname -a
Linux box 5.8.0-26-generic #27-Ubuntu SMP Wed Oct 21 22:29:16 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
juan@box:~$ cat /etc/os-release
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="20.10 (Groovy Gorilla)"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 20.10"
VERSION_ID="20.10"
HOME_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
PRIVACY_POLICY_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/legal/terms-and-policies/privacy-policy"
VERSION_CODENAME=groovy
UBUNTU_CODENAME=groovy
juan@box:~$
```

Sometimes I have to work with the GUI disabled. Everytime I do, I notice that networking is stopped in the VM, unless I login to the console first (in my case, VMWare Fusion). The server is not pingable and SSH fails (connection timeouts). After logging in to the console, ping will immediately work.

It can easily be replicated by rebooting the VM, run a continuous ping from the host, login to the console, and within a second the ping would start working.

I timed this and found the following in `syslog`:

```
Nov  3 19:41:18 box NetworkManager[1310]: <info>  [1604428878.1898] device (ens38): state change: activated -> deactivating (reason 'connection-removed', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Nov  3 19:41:18 box dbus-daemon[1182]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.nm-dispatcher.service' requested by ':1.10' (uid=0 pid=1310 comm="/usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon " label="unconfined")
Nov  3 19:41:18 box NetworkManager[1310]: <info>  [1604428878.2087] device (ens38): state change: deactivating -> disconnected (reason 'connection-removed', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
```

My best guess is that it has something to do with GNOME and NetworkManager. It sounds as if they were waiting for an initial user to login to the GUI login manager first before starting the networking services.

Thanks a lot in advance!

PS: sorry if this sounds trivial, but I haven't touched GUIs in a long time.

PPS: I know I can just disable and replace NetworkManager, but I want to stick with everything "Linux on the desktop" stuff for now.

Answer (score 0):

Found it:

```
nmcli> describe connection.autoconnect

=== [autoconnect] ===
[NM property description]
Whether or not the connection should be automatically connected by
NetworkManager when the resources for the connection are available.
TRUE to automatically activate the connection,
FALSE to require manual intervention to activate the connection.

Note that autoconnect is not implemented for VPN profiles.
See "secondaries" as an alternative to automatically connect VPN profiles.


nmcli>
```